# Masslessness of Goldstone Bosons

Tags: mass, symmetry, symmetry-breaking

I have a question about the origin of the massless nature of [Goldstone bosons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldstone_boson).

This is what I understood: we know thanks to Goldstone's theorem that from the breaking of continuous symmetries emerge massless Bosons, which are kind of excitations along the direction of the symmetry generators.
I understand where the theorem comes from: I've read different proofs, some of which utilize the conserved charge of the symmetry to generate the excited states, and others that analyze the second order approximation of the potential to deduce the existence of massless excitations. In brief: I think I understand the mechanics behind all of that.
Nonetheless, I can't quite see why intuitively these bosons need to be massless: to me it is like if the presence of symmetry-breaking prevents the modes from having "initial" energy (coming from the mass) in the first place, but why must that be the case? Does it have something to do with the property of the group of the continuous symmetries? Why can't we just have massive ground states and then excitations along the directions of the broken symmetries?

This also for me collides with the fact that in lattice Hamiltonian the introduction of symmetry breaking interaction (like time or lattice reversal symmetries) introduces a gap (mass) in the dispersion relation (otherwise gapeless) of the modes on the lattice. How can two such apparently similar procedures lead to such different phenomena?

Comment: The article you read explains that SSB entails degenerate vacua, and the Goldstone excitations must be "soft", massless connectors among them, no? Did you appreciate the null eigenvector argument?

Comment: Two questions: (1) What do you mean by "massive ground state"? Masses are defined by energies relative to the vacuum state. The energy of the vacuum state itself is irrelevant in this context.  (2) Why do you expect a gap on the lattice? Do you mean a *finite volume* lattice? The gap is due to finite volume in the spatial domain (an IR thing), not to discretization in the spatial domain (a UV thing). SSB in the strict sense doesn't occur in finite volume, either.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers/questions. To Cosmas: yes, I appreciate the argument as a formal proof", but it didn't give me an inuitive explanation.

Comment: To Chiral Anomaly: so, by "massless bosons" usually is understood "bosons with spectra continuously connected to the ground state energy"? As for the second point: the reference to the lattice case was done actually to consider a different phenomenon (symmetry breaking implies mass appearence) which in a sense shows an opposite behaviour with respect to the masslessness of modes of broken symmetries.